# Error when using Batik in a Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, batik

I am not sure if the problem lies with the apache server or batik. I am trying to convert svg to image in java using Batik in a servlet. When i instantiate SVGConverter in a servlet

`SVGConverter svgConverter = new SVGConverter()`

Apache returns this error:

```
Jun 26, 2012 3:28:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [FCImg] in context with path [/jsp_batik] threw  exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/apps/rasterizer/SVGConverter
at FCImg.doPost(FCImg.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have included the correct jar files in the project and there doesnt seem to be any errors when compiling the java file that instantiates the SVGConverter object.

Any suggestions are helpful, thanks!

edit: I just had to include the necessary jar files (all the batik jar files) in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely batik-rasterizer.jar is missing in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Hmm, I included it in the root lib folder. When i added batik-rasterizer.jar to WEB-INF/lib. It still gives me an error saying `NoClassDefFound` but now it states that it could not initialize `SVGConverter`. Any suggestions for this? Also, just for my own knowledge, why does it need to be included in the WEB-INF/lib and not just the root lib folder?

Comment: I got it working. I also needed to include the batik-transcoder.jar file in WEB-INF/lib. Now what i dont understand is why does it need to be included in specifically that lib folder.

Comment: WEB-INF/lib is the only folder in a .war that is considered for .jar files. It usually helps to use a build tool like Maven/Ivy/Gradle/Buildr/… to avoid such errors.